# One page website, open section with changing hash AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

This might be a silly question, but suppose I have a one page website, where all sections are hidden and shown only when the button menu is clicked to reveal that particular section and hide the other ones. Now, when I reload the page it always opens the default first page. What I would like to use is something that

www.example/index.html#**page1**

or

www.example/index.html#**page2**

or

www.example/index.html#**page3**

index.html page:

menu:

```
<ul>
<li>page1</li>
<li>page2</li>
<li>page3</li>
</ul
```

sections:

```
<div id="page1">content</div>
<div id="page2" style="display:none">content</div>
<div id="page3" style="display:none">content</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Checkout Backbone.js. It mit just be what you are looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SEO standards, this is totally impracticable, but if you decide to go anyway, you can use `jQuery`.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#page1">page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">page3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="page1" class="pages">content 1</div>
<div id="page2" class="pages" style="display:none">content 2</div>
<div id="page3" class="pages" style="display:none">content 3</div>
```

**jQuery (Javascript)**

```
$(function () {     
    $(window).on("hashchange", function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash != "") {
            $(".pages").hide();
            $(hash).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I know, not good for SEO. But this one doesn't have to be. Anyway, your solution is what I already have, but how do I open lets say page2 if the url is only index.html? Can't I use something like index.html#page2

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's trick to test it on jsFiddle, so give it a go.

Comment: Just be aware that the `hashchange` event might not work on some browsers. Have a double check before deciding to use it.

Comment: Also, if the answer solves your problem, please mark it as the solution. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that [this](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs) [might](http://benward.me/blog/tumblr-3231388630) [be a](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch) [bad](http://ngriffith.com/2012/02/20/hash-banging-the-intertubes) [idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page1">page1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2">page2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page3">page3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="page1">page1</div>
    <div id="page2">page2</div>
    <div id="page3">page3</div>
    <script>
      var pageIds = ['page1','page2','page3'];
      function hidePage(){
        for(var i=0;i<pageIds.length;i++){
          document.getElementById(pageIds[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      function getPage(){
        var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
        return document.getElementById(hash);
      }
      function showPage(){
        var currentPage = getPage();
        if(currentPage){
          currentPage.style.cssText = 'display:block';
          }else{
          document.getElementById('page1').style.cssText = 'display:block';
        }
      }
      function initPage(){
        hidePage();
        showPage();
      }
      initPage();
      setInterval(function(){
        initPage();
      },300);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has cache library, you can use that library to keep last opened tab or link.